# How to list all possible combinations of taking 5 out of N objects in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The title may not perfectly describe what my intention here is. Let's suppose I have 14 objects in total and I want to pick 5 of them. Using a calculator, we can see that there are 2002 possibilities. Now if I have 17 objects and I want to pick 5 again, now there are 6188 possibilities. The problem is that online calculators don't list them.

My intention is to make Excel list the possible combinations of taking 5 objects out of N, being N a number that I would put in, for example, cell A1 (although it will always be a number between 6 and 18). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can we assume that you don't want **permutations**  That is if you have picked 1,2,3,4,5 that we can ignore stuff like 1,2,3,5,4 ??

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify it. Yes, we can ignore it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the 14 items in **A1** through **A14** then run:

```
Sub Kombos()
    Dim amount As Long
    amount = 14

    ZZ = 1
    For i = 1 To amount - 4
        For j = i + 1 To amount - 3
            For k = j + 1 To amount - 2
                For L = k + 1 To amount - 1
                    For m = L + 1 To amount
                        Cells(ZZ, 2) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(j, 1) & Cells(k, 1) & Cells(L, 1) & Cells(m, 1)
                        ZZ = ZZ + 1
                    Next m
                Next L
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Ran it a couple times to get all lists until 18 and it's perfect. Thank you!